# Python Path Issues with Sphinx?

Tags: python, path, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm running into a *lot* of trouble trying to use Sphinx autodoc for a python package, and I think the issue is a path one, but I'm not sure how to solve? Wondering if anyone might know?

I'm trying it out with just a super basic module setup with a single main.py inside of 'my_project' that looks like:
[image: main.py contents and file structure]

In both cases below, I have just a basic conf.py and index.rst file:
[image: conf.py and index.rst file contents]

---

### Scenario 1 (works fine)

When I use the `sphinx-quickstart` command to build out the folder tree and specify **'N'** when asks if I want to separate source and build directories, it seems to all work fine and I am able to successfully build the html and it finds and reads my_project.main without issue. In this case, I get a folder tree that looks like:

```
.
├── docs
│   ├── build
│   ├──_static
│   ├──_templates
│   ├──conf.py
│   └──index.rst
└── my_project
    └── main
```

---

### Scenario 2 (not working)

However: When I use the `sphinx-quickstart` command to build out the folder tree and specify **'Y'** when it asks about separating source and build, now I get a nicer more ordered folder tree within my `./docs`. So now I have:

```
.
├── docs
│   ├── build
│   └── source
│        ├──_static
│        ├──_templates
│        ├──conf.py
│        └──index.rst
└── my_project
    └── main
```

But the nesting of the conf.py (I think?) seems to be causing path trouble? Now if I try and build the html, I get an import error:

```py
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'main' from module 'my_project'; 
the following exception was raised:
No module named 'my_project'
```

---

So it seems that the conf.py is not probably finding and adding the top-level path in this case?

---

### So, I wonder:

1. How can I add a folder 2 levels 'up' from current to the sys.path? I can get one level 'up' using `..` but `...` does not work to go up two? It does not work when I try something like:
   `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('...')) # three dots does doesn't work?`
2. Am I missing something else here? how should I be using the 'nested' sphinx-quickstart setup to properly find my modules using autodoc?

Answer (score 0):

As you may have surmised, `autodoc` needs to be able to import your code in order to make your docs.  There are two ways to do this:

1. The easy way is to edit the `sys.path.insert` line in `conf.py`.  You almost had this right: instead of `...`, it should be `../..`.
2. The better way (in my opinion) is to (i) install your package in a virtual environment and (ii) install/run sphinx in that same environment.  This way, you don't need to mess with the import path at all.  Installing your code also makes it a lot easier to share/reuse (even if only between other scripts on your machine).

   If you don't know how to do this, I'd recommend looking into a tool called [flit](https://flit.pypa.io/en/latest/index.html).  The whole process should look something like this (although note that I haven't actually tested any of these commands):

   ```bash
   # Create a `pyproject.toml` file:
   flit init

   # Create a new virtual environment
   python -m venv sphinx-env
   . sphinx-env/bin/activate

   # Install your package and sphinx 
   pip install . sphinx

   # Run sphinx
   cd docs
   make html
   ```

Comment: Thank you @KaleKundert, that is very helpful. And yes: the syntax `../..` seems to work well now. I think your recommendation for a venv is great as well. I was using a venv in my example, but I think my Homebrew installation of sphinx was causing part of the problem as well? I have removed Homebrew and now running Sphinx through the venv install seems to work well. Thank you.